# StackOverflow Ajax problem with latest Chrome

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, google-chrome

There seems to be problems with running Chrome version 4.0.249.89 (38071) on StackOverflow - The edit toolbar disappears, clicking on comments to view the comments, replicates the comment input box...Has anyone else experienced this...? Funnily enough Meta works fine!

[Clicking on comments to expand list of comments replicate the comment input boxes](http://www.box.net/shared/pf741z68e8)

[Edit Toolbar buttons disappeared](http://www.box.net/shared/55jz7206f2)

Comment: ...hosting screenshots with Flash? Is that web site insane?

Comment: @jleedev: umm....it's hosted on box.net...and yes tis crap!

Comment: Clear your cache maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beta version is not officially supported, so you probably won't get much of an answer from the time other than "use a stable version"

<sub>Your images don't load</sub>

Comment: @Downvoter: Had to give you -1, because it has worked consistently up to now, as I type this in Chrome, Meta seems to behave better, which suggests to me, that something in the Ajax/JS on SO is not responding under this version of Chrome as I type this.

Comment: @Downvoter: Your answer is not helpful either! Explain in my comment about how meta is working perfectly and not SO?!

Comment: @Downvoter: BTW it should be mentioned that there is an error in the script through the Developer>Javascript console!

Comment: @tommie, my answer remains, it's not officially supported, no matter what the scenario is; and as such they probably won't spend time fixing it

Comment: this is an officially released version of Chrome, though.. same one my about menu says.

Comment: @Jeff, it's my version too, but I downloaded the beta version... perhaps they already released officially then

Answer (score 1):

We can't reproduce this in Chrome. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Funnily enough, something wonky happened and chrome stable refused to work as I put up a question on superuser about it and reported it to google...http://superuser.com/questions/114239/google-chrome-4-0-249-89-not-working and http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=0d9093c5c0ad982c&hl=en ... so far nada...zilch...it was working fine then gave up the ghost....dunno