# A user's reputation shows a Object (seen on Chrome Canary)

Tags: bug, status-declined, reputation, google-chrome

The reputation of the author of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596766/newline-in-filewriter/3599516#3599516) shows as `object` to me.
[image]

Even after clearing the cache or without being logged in.
Only this user seems to be affected, and AFAICT it affects all his answers.

I have not that problem with safari though.
I know it's canary and it might just be a bug in the browser, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Don't see that here. Looks like a JS bug in your browser to me. Seeing as this is the Chrome beta channel, I'd say that breakage like this is the browser's fault, not SO.

Comment: The actual problem here is that Tim Stones reputation reached "1470569069" and so was easier to represent in base-36.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, just double checked to confirm that there wasn't an update that I missed. I still don't see that user's reputation displaying as an object though.

Comment: This is fantastically hilarious, I'm not sure how I missed this post before. Incidentally, I cannot reproduce this on myself in Chrome dev.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby No one has reached 1 billion reputation yet. The user with the highest reputation as of writing is Jon Skeet with 585k reputation.

Answer (score 13):

SE does not support beta browsers, if this is not reproducible in the latest stable version of Chrome it won't be fixed. It makes no sense for SE to work around bugs in unstable versions that might not be present in the final release.

Comment: Yep, this exactly

Comment: Says similarly here, all the way back in the Chrome browser 4.x days, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39458/160875

Comment: It would be rather horrible if thousands of Chrome users started objectifying me, though.